# NSUserDefaults error for "objectAtIndex"

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsuserdefaults

Getting an error message on this line of code:

```
Team *team = [leagueLocal.teams objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
```

Error is "Use of undeclared identifier 'indexpath'"... but I'm not sure what I would put at **objectAtIndex:** other than **indexpath.row**, because thats what works for me in the TableView part of this app.

Big picture, I'm trying to use NSUserDefaults save the Team Name that was selected.  Team Names are being pulled in via JSON from a web service.

Here is the full code for the NSUserDefaults part I have so far:

```
   // Create User Defaults Variable
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   // Tell it where to look
Sport *sportLocal = [sports objectAtIndex:0];
League *leagueLocal = [sportLocal.leagues objectAtIndex:0];
Team *team = [leagueLocal.teams objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];  //  This is where error is

   // Store the data, this is the stuff I want to save
[defaults setObject:team.abbreviation forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"teamAbbreviation%d", _buttonNumber]];

   // After saving, synchronize data
[defaults synchronize];
```

Thanks for the help!  Let me know if any more info is needed, or where I can help clarify if needed.

**Edit**- I added an NSLog in my `viewDidLoad` right below the error to see what I was getting, and it came back null: `NSLog(@"object at index: %@", team.abbreviation);`

Comment: If you are using this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for example, then the name of your variable is `indexPath` (note the upper case P).

Comment: Check ur indexpath by log whether ur having the proper indexpath value r not.

Comment: @Scott Its in my viewDidLoad, and even when I change it to just `indexPath` it still comes up with the same error.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @Ganapathy What should I use for my `NSLog`? Right now I'm using `NSLog(@"%@", indexPath);` but that obviously won't work for the same reasons that `indexPath` didn't work originally.  Just gives me an error and asks if I meant `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: @Scott I just did an NSLog in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and I am getting all of the team names in the UITable, so that is correct(`NSLog(@"Team names %@", team.name);`). But I get nothing back when I put `NSLog(@"IndexPath %@", indexPath);' so does that make more sense to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this is inside viewDidLoad, then unless you've initialized the indexPath variable it will not be valid. It's only valid in your tableView methods because it's passed in through the function.

You have a couple options to grab the indexPath that your looking for though:

```
Team *team = [leagueLocal.teams objectAtIndex:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:k];
//where i and k are integers that indicate the row/section for the tableViewCell your looking for...(k would just be equal to 0 if you only have one section)
```

Or another way would be if the user has previously selected what your looking for then you can use:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath=[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
Team *team = [leagueLocal.teams objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];//now you can use it the way you have it written in your question
```

Hope it helps!